# has-many does not work

Tags: clojure, korma

I've got 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE public.user_account
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_account_id_seq'::regclass),
  email character(50) NOT NULL,
  password character(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT user_account_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE public.recipe
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('recipe_id_seq'::regclass),
  user_account_id integer NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  description text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT recipe_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT recipe_user_account_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_account_id)
      REFERENCES public.user_account (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

This is my clojure declaration

```
(declare user_account recipe)

(kc/defentity user_account
           (kc/entity-fields :email :password)
           (kc/has-many recipe {:fk :user_account_id})
           )

(kc/defentity recipe
              (kc/entity-fields :user_account_id :name :description)
              (kc/belongs-to user_account {:fk :user_account_id})
              )
```

And I can not select the `user_account` table with `recipe`

```
user=> (sql-only (kc/select user_account  (with recipe) (where {:id 1})))
"SELECT \"user_account\".\"email\", \"user_account\".\"password\" FROM \"user_account\" WHERE (\"user_account\".\"id\" = ?)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. The solution was to addition the pk field to `entity-fields` list in the parent entity. It really is not intuitive, and seems that the problem is in a poor documentation. So the solution should be:

```
(declare user_account recipe)

(kc/defentity user_account
           (kc/entity-fields :id :email :password)
;                            ^^^ fix is here 
           (kc/has-many recipe {:fk :user_account_id})
           )

(kc/defentity recipe
              (kc/entity-fields :user_account_id :name :description)
              (kc/belongs-to user_account {:fk :user_account_id})
              )
```

Comment: A switched to yesql because of this problem and also poor documentation. But thanks for the answer